# How do I dynamically extend in Jinja2 to render different nav-bars

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm building a simple web app using: Python, Flask, and Jinja2.

I have two nav-bar template pages: basic-nav-bar.html and user-nav-bar.html

My goal is to have other pages inherit either of these two nav-bars.

For example, this page is the user's dashboard, so I'd like it to extend the user-nav-bar.html page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Dashboard {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

When I try to simply add an additional "extends" statement, it does not work, and I'd like the base.html page to be extended.

Could you show me how I'd do this using my example, please?

Comment: I've also tried using the include statement but that is only useful for static pages, not a nav-bar with links.

Comment: I should clarify, links in the nav-bar do work when using "include", however, drop down items from the nav-bar do not function. As in, clicking on an item in the nav-bar that should pull down more options, does not "pull down" to reveal said options.

Comment: A child template can only have one base template, so your solution was correct: include the respective navbar's template. However, if your drop down navbars are not working, that's a separate issue. You should show us the source code of the navbar templates as well.

Comment: The dropdown menus in the nav bar code work when included on every single webpage (which is obviously a drag as it's a ton of repeated code), so I know it's not the nav bar code. What I did end up doing was using Jinja2 "if statements" in my base.html with a variable passed from the child templates. It's not a perfect solution but its so much better than repeated code!

Answer (score 0):

It's not an ideal solution, but what I did was include the following if statements in my base.html:

```
{% block navbars %}
      {% if loggedIn %}
      // code for user logged in nav bar
      {% else %}
      // code for basic nav bar
      {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then, using the user-dashboard.html as an example of the child template inheriting base.html:

```
{% set loggedIn = True %} 
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Dashboard {% endblock %}

{% block navbars %} {{ super() }} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

This worked.